# Can I recycle waxy cardboard (in Greater Vancouver)?

Tags: recycling, composting, paper, packaging

Does anyone know what to do with these containers?

Even though some of them are labelled "#3 Please recycle this container" I'm quite sure they can't be put with mixed paper or cardboard recycling [because of the food bits](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/1149/1056) and residual oils on them.

I'm pretty sure they aren't made with any plastic because it was easy to tear like paper or cardboard. I also used the "fire test" and found that it burns instead of melting, though the flame quickly went out.

Could they be compostable? They have a waxy lining. Are all waxes safe for compost?

[image: a waxy cardboard box covered in food residue and viewed from two angles]

I'm located in the Greater Vancouver area of British Columbia if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The City of Vancouver’s Waste Wizard says put them in the green bin. They also have a hotline you can call. Why wait for an answer here?[image]

Comment: This may help other people with the same question if it appears as a search result in Google.